# lsyncd Error: There can only be one config file in command line. Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, synchronization

I am trying to mirror two folders using lsyncd command. Here are the steps I followed.

1. Install the `lsyncd` package
2. Run the following code:

   `sudo lsyncd /home/dxterity1/NGSNAS1/Screen Shots /home/dxterity1/DataStore/Screenshots`

I am getting an error: `There can only be one config file in command line.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lsyncd documentation shows this synopsis:

```
lsyncd [OPTIONS] CONFIG-FILE
lsyncd [OPTIONS] -rsync SOURCEDIR TARGET ...
```

So your command should probably be something like:

```
sudo lsyncd -rsync '/home/dxterity1/NGSNAS1/Screen Shots' /home/dxterity1/DataStore/Screenshots
```

(The first path should be quoted since it contains white space.)